# Adding a drop-down (select tag) option under Menu Settings in WordPress Admin

Tags: customization, theme-development, custom-field, menus, metabox

I looked (surfed) around a lot to get idea of how can I add custom field/drop-down under "Menu Settings" in WordPress Admin.

I want a `select` tag with options from which I can get value based on the current selected menu.

Below image shows the basic idea what I am trying to get:

[image]

I want this to associate value for each selected menu and get it for dynamic theme style for the menu.

P.S. I am new to WordPress Development, please bear me.

Your help would be really appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: So you want to have a different menu for each theme? Can't imagine the case like yours. Can you explain the aim?

Comment: No I do not want different menus for each theme. I would simply say I want custom select tag under menu settings. Just that.

Comment: Can you make clear what's the purpose? The answer depends on